# How to blur custom button's title like system UIButton's title when touching in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, custom-button

I have following custom button:

```
class GreenButton: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    backgroundColor = .green
    layer.cornerRadius = 4
    setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)
}
}
```

But I want its title to blur when touching, just like how system UIButton behaves. If I declare my button like this `GreenButton(type: .system)`, its title blurs, but font is not changing. If I declare it as `GreenButton()`, its font is ok, but its title is not blurring. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a different color for the highlighted state:

```
private func setup() {
    backgroundColor = .green
    layer.cornerRadius = 4
    // set title normal color
    setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    // set title highlighted color
    setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
    titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this as below:

```
class GreenButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        setTitleColor(UIColor(white:1.0 , alpha: 0.5), for: .normal)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    }

    private func setup() {
        backgroundColor = .green
        layer.cornerRadius = 4
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)
    }
}
```